# Why cart React-Redux doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a shopping cart using react-redux. I want to be able to add a product to the cart after that add the amount (inital 1 piece). And if the user wants it can update that amount (higer or lower).

At this moment I keep getting the same problem, one product is added but the user cannot update it anymore.

Dispatch code

```
  function addToCart() {
    console.log(oneBox);

    dispatch(addCart(oneBox));
  }
```

then the action code:

```
export const addCart = (oneBox) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(appLoading());

    const curCart = getState().cart;

    console.log(curCart);

    let productCart = { ...oneBox };

    productCart = { ...productCart, amount: 1 };

    if (!curCart.cart) {
      dispatch(addCartSuccess([productCart]));
    } else {
      if (parseInt(curCart.cart.map((cart) => cart.id)) === oneBox.id) {
        dispatch(updateCartSuccess(oneBox));
      } else {
        dispatch(addCartSuccess([productCart]));
      }
    }

    dispatch(appDoneLoading());
  };
}:
```

then the reducer code:

```
export default  (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {

  switch (type) {
    case ADD_CART_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state.cart, ...payload };

    case UPDATE_CART_SUCCESS:
      console.log(payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map((cart) => {
          if (cart.id === payload.id) {
            return {
              ...cart,
              amount: payload.amount + 1,
            };
          }

          return cart;
        }),
      };
```

What it needs to do is first to check if the productid that is send (oneBox) is already in the cart, if not add the product to the cart (works fine). And if the product is already in the cart just update the amount (not working).

Anyone can see what i'm doing wrong here?

ps. Bear with me i'm a junior developer. I'm not known with the class based react or mapStateToProps.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the line when you compare cart with oneBox, because calling `parseInt` on an array will parse just the first element. I assume that you want to check if one of the item.id in the cart match with oneBox.id. This is one way to do it

```
if (curCart.cart.filter((cart) => cart.id === oneBox.id).length) {
  dispatch(updateCartSuccess(oneBox));
}
```

code above filter the cart that match oneBox.id.. if nothing is found, then it will result empty array with length of 0 (falsy). and if found, the array will be greater than 0 (most likely 1, which is truthy)